# Rails ActiveRecord callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having an issue with a date format. I have a time picker that has the date in a funky format (well, it's a nice format, actually, but not to the computer). I'm trying to have `Chronic` parse the date so that it can be saved properly.

At first, I was doing, in the create action of my controller:

```
params[:event][:start] = Chronic.parse(params[:event][:start])
```

but if and when validation fails, it sends the parsed value back to the view, and my datetimepicker is all botched, then.

So, I thought... callback? In my model, I added:

```
private
  def date_change
    self.start = Chronic.parse(self.start)
  end
```

I tried `before_save`, `before_validation`, `after_validation`... but nothing seems to get that date formatted correctly.

As it stands, I keep getting `ArgumentError in EventsController#create - Argument out of range`. I assume that's because the database is expecting a properly formatted datetime object.

Any idea on how I can accomplish my goal, here, of not changing the `params`, but still being able to save a properly formatted object?

Comment: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example5 - it can display however I'd like, but it's going to get sent to the controller exactly how it's shown. That's what I'm using Chronic to parse the data and get a real datetime object. I'm not sure how else to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the problem is occurring the the `start=` mutator method that ActiveRecord supplies. If you're doing things like this in your controller:

```
@event.update_attributes(params[:events])
@event = Event.create(params[:event])
#...
```

then `create` and `update_attributes` should call `start=` internally. That should allow you to put the Chronic stuff in your own `start=`:

```
def start=(t)
  super(Chronic.parse(t))
end
```

You might need to adjust that for non-String `t`s, I'm not sure what `Chronic.parse(Time.now)`, for example, would do. You could also call `write_attribute(:start, Chronic.parse(t))` or `self[:start] = Chronic.parse(t)` if you didn't want to punt to `super`.

Note that `before_validation` and similar handlers will be called too late to bypass whatever default string-to-timestamp conversion ActiveRecord is doing but a mutator override should happen at the right time.

Alternatively, you could parse the time in the controller with something like this:

```
event = params[:events].dup
events[:start] = Chronic.parse(events[:start])
@event = Event.create(event)
```

Comment: So, basically, just override a setter method. I like it. I just tried it, and it still sends back the parsed datetime to the view if validation fails. That, in turn, breaks my date picker...

Comment: Sounds like you have a view problem, the view should be converting the time to whatever format your JS needs. I still think your picker should be sending and receiving ISO 8601 format though.

Comment: Nope... Once the `@event` tries to get built (by tinkering with the params, even after copying them) it feeds that parsed info back to the view. If you wanna check out all the code, I wouldn't mind - https://github.com/Mallanaga/palv2

Comment: Your view is allowed to do more than `<%= @event.start %>`, if your widget needs `@event.start` in a specific format then do the translation in the view. Or fix the widget to be more flexible in what date it accepts.

Comment: It's part of a form. `= f.text_field :start, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'start' ` The only way I know to manipulate date/time is with `.strftime`, and I don't know how to use it in a form like that. I don't know enough about the widget, unfortunately, to 'fix' it. =/

Answer (score 0):

Assumption is the mother of all mess ups :)

- are you sure the callback is hit? Because if it would, and the error occurred (like it did), wouldn't it still send back the incorrect data (because parsed) back to the view? In case of doubt: log something to make sure it is hit.
- are you sure which field causes the `Argument out of range` error.

Most cases bugs are so hard to find/fix because we assume we know the error, but we are looking at the error in the wrong way.

Easy ways to test which attribute causes the error:

- open `rails console`, build an object with the parameters, save it, and ask the errors. Something like

  e = Event.new(params[:event]) # copy params verbatim from your logfile
  e.save
  e.errors

and that will display which field causes the error.

Alternatively: use pry and add a line `binding.pry` just after the save, so you inspect the `errors` (more [info](http://yorickpeterse.com/articles/debugging-with-pry/))

#### Answer (assuming your assumption was correct)

I see two options to do what you want:

- use the `after_validation` callback, if you are sure the data will always be correct, and correctly parsed by `Chronic`. This way if validation is passed, then convert the field and normally nothing can go wrong anymore, and the value is never sent to the browser again.

Note: if some other attribute is causing the error, this callback is never hit, of course. Because it does not pass the validation.

- use a virtual attribute, e.g. `start_str`, which is a visual representation of your start, and 
  `before_save` convert it to `start`. It does not really matter that much here, because if validation fails, you just show `start_str` and not the "real" `start` field.

Comment: I hear you on the assumptions... I know it's the date though, as I had it working with a different method, but wanted to switch it up. I tested it in the console. Building an event with `start: Date.now` instead of `start: '01/24/2014 4:29 PM'`, and all is well. I tried using `after_validation`, though... no dice. I know the data will always be correct, so I'm not worried about it. It doesn't seem to be hitting the after_validation method, though...

Comment: In fact... I just tried building (in the app) with just the date, and nothing else, and validation doesn't fail - it goes straight to the `argument out of range` error. Seems like the Model won't even build with incompatible data? I don't want to use a virtual attribute - they don't validate nicely.

Comment: Which line on the controller is that? Can you show us a stacktrace?

Comment: Adding a virtual attribute is really simple: just `attr_accessor start_str`. I do not get the remark about the validation? If you need to validate it you will need to add your own validation, but you are adding a specific conversion here as well. You might also look into Rails default date format. I can just assign a string to my date field and rails converts it automatically, unless it is a weird format of course. But the out of range error sounds like something else.